# Issue while installing Google Cloud on WIndow 7

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have downloaded the installer from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows and trying to install but its giving me error "Output folder: C:\gcloud
Downloading Google Cloud SDK core.
Download failed: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"

[image]

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or using a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

As Scott suggested If you are behind a corporate proxy or firewall, the gcloud command-line tool may not be able to access the internet with its default settings.
If you cannot disable the firewall or remove the proxy, you can install from [versioned archives](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives) for a non-interactive installation of a specific version of Cloud SDK.